# Django & MySQL - Connecting to the database per-request is very slow

Tags: mysql, django, performance

We just set up [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) for monitoring and it says that 90% of our request time is spent in `MySQLdb:connect` — between one and ten seconds per request!

Django seems to open a new MySQL connection for every request. How can I further diagnose what's going on? Are there any Django or MySQL settings could I use to make connecting to MySQL faster?

Note: I've ruled out DNS since the frontends connect to the DB using a numeric IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that django will close the connection at each request and re-initialize it again; as the db code listens on a signal:

`signals.request_finished.connect(close_connection)` in `django/db/__init__.py`

One solution is to implement [connection pooling for MySQL using SQLAlchemy](http://node.to/wordpress/2010/02/11/database-connection-pool-solution-for-django-mysql/) which is the least intrusive and most upgrade friendly I have seen.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but your solution seems to be the only reasonable one.

Comment: That link doesn’t work anymore. Any related references?